# Server error when taking website live

Tags: php, html

I made some changes in a website. The website was initial static and to make some changes I changed the links of the website to .php.

I made the changes and it was working perfectly fine in localhost. I saw no errors and no warnings.

However when I moved it to a live server I saw this problem.

```
Server error
The website encountered an error while retrieving http://prakashchhetri.com.np/projects/hmaloha/. It may be down for maintenance or configured incorrectly.
Here are some suggestions:
Reload this webpage later.
HTTP Error 500 (Internal Server Error): An unexpected condition was encountered while the server was attempting to fulfill the request.
```

I faced similar problem before but it was due to some syntax error in my PHP scripts (In my previous projects).
However in this project, I dont think I have made any errors and If I had made any, the project would not run in  my localhost.

I checked the website live in two different servers but still the same problem

Comment: Check apache error logs.

Comment: Error 500 most likely means you have a fatal error. Check your error logs.

Comment: post here the errorlog

Comment: Post some relevant PHP code as well.

Comment: Very silly problem, I changed the links to PHP but forgot to remove `<?xml version="1.0"?>` from the script. It is working now. But thank to all

Comment: You have short open tags enabled and you want to likely disable it now. See as well [Are PHP short tags acceptable to use?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/200640/367456) and http://www.php.net/short_open_tag

Answer (score 1):

Be sure to check both apache and php error logs (if they're separate). You'll find your answer in there.

Alternatively, assuming php is the culprit, you can momentarily enable the following settings in php.ini:

```
display_errors = On
html_errors = On
error_reporting = E_ALL | E_STRICT
```

just be sure that you disable these again in the future so that you're not exposing users to potentially sensitive information.

Answer (score 0):

make sure the user www-data has permission to read the php script